# Why INFO log is shown when logging level is set to ERROR? (Sprint Boot logging level problem)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, logging

I have a Spring Boot application which uses Spring Boot version 2.7.0.

I have this in application.properties:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

And I see this in the log:

```
2024-02-29 12:23:51 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.Version | HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.0.2.Final
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | WARN | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl | HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl | HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl | HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:sap://*************]
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl | HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=****}
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl | HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2024-02-29 12:23:52 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections | HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2024-02-29 12:23:53 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect
2024-02-29 12:23:54 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator | HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Then I update application.properties like this:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.*=ERROR
```

Now I see this in the log:

```
2024-02-29 12:27:44 IST | INFO | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect
```

My problem is, why do I still see this particular INFO log from Hibernate?
(When I set Hibernate logging level to ERROR, other Hibernate INFO and WARN logs are gone. But not this particular one.)